# Decorating object on method missing: yay or nay?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, decorator

One of the reasons I don't really use the decorator pattern is having to call .decorate every time I need access to the decorator methods, which is quite often.

Would it be a good practice decorating on method missing, eg:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def foo
    "foo!"
  end

  def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
    if UserDecorator.instance_methods.include? m
       UserDecorator.new( self ).decorate.send(m, args)
    end
  end
end

class UserDecorator < WhateverDecorator
  def bar
    "bar!"
  end
end
```

If it's not a good practice, could you be so kind as to explain why?

Comment: Seems fine if it works for you.

Comment: Can you explain a use case? Right now what I see is `Module#include` with a bunch of overhead.

Comment: Well 1) to quote my boss "one must always use the decorator pattern" or I guess it's the end of the world as we know it, and 2) don't want to go through all code and refactor to decorate objects where required.

Comment: But that is not a decorator pattern. Decorator pattern generally uses dependency injection such that the user decorator would always be given an instance of User or subclasses there of and you would interact with that decorator regardless of what user instance was passed in. You would not be interacting with User directly but rather interacting with it via a wrapping class user decorator